# How to detect if users are near each other - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I know how to use region monitoring to trigger an event when a user enters or exits a certain region, however, I am if it is possible to do the same thing in case two (or more) users are near each other (around 100 meters from each other).

I'm afraid iBeacon is not what I need.

Is this is something that can be done through CloudKit maybe? I am confused after searching for an answer the whole night without any luck. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through [Apple's Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/multipeerconnectivity).

It is limited up to 7 other connected iOS devices at a time within 100 meters.

There's also a WWDC video on it here too [WWDC13](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/708/).

Comment: Thank you man, but this is not what i'm looking for. I don't want it to rely on bluetooth technology, and it's also very limited.

Comment: I'm thinking about something like "Happn", or maybe "Uber". Do you maybe know how those guys are doing this?

Comment: @MaorDuani This sounds like something you'll need to manage remotely and create a web service to communicate to the devices. I integrated multipeer with success and meant my devices could communicate regardless of wifi or cellular connection. If you're thinking of something like Uber though, this will involve something remote.

Comment: @Jim Tierney Hello, great answer :). I'm looking to do something similar but instead of connecting to nearby devices I need to locate the closest ones (no interaction between each other). 1. Would Multipeer work for this? 2. If it detects up to 7 devices, can the other devices also connect to another 7 a so on? E.g. user 1 connects to 7 users and then those 7 users connects to another 7 users so now there are 50 connected users